# How to run a lambda expression that is a value on a map

Tags: java, lambda, maps

I'm quite new to java and I am trying to create a set out of objects that are acquired through lambda expressions in a map. Basically, I am getting a value from the map (lambda expression) and running it to get a Boolean. However, I'm getting an error when running the .apply on the expression. Any ideas on how to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

```
        Map<String, Predicate<IndexSub>> order_function = new HashMap<>();
        order_function.put("AlternativesValues", x -> false);
        order_function.put("AlternativesConstituent", x -> x.getCloseCons());
        order_function.put("EquityValues", x -> false);
        order_function.put("EquityCloseConstituent", x -> x.getCloseCons());
        order_function.put("EquityOpenConstituent", x -> x.getOpenCons());
        order_function.put("FixedValues", x -> false);
        order_function.put("FixedReturns", x -> x.getCloseCons());
        order_function.put("FixedStatistics", x -> x.getOpenCons());

        //getCloseCons and getOpenCons return true/false    

        Set<String> orderable_sub = new HashSet<String>();

        for (IndexSub s : tenant_subscriptions) {
                                 //DataProduct is a string
            if (order_function.get(DataProduct).apply(s) == true){
                orderable_sub.add(s.getIndexId());
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is tenant_subscriptions?

Comment: What exactly is the error? if `DataProduct` is an integer you should parse it to String as your map has String keys.

Comment: What is `DataProduct`?

Comment: What is `IndexSub` & `DataProduct`. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: You get a NullPointerException because `order_function.get(DataProduct)` returns `null`. You have to either put the correct Integer values as keys into it or retrieve with the correct string.

Comment: Side note: `if(boolean_condition == true)` could be shortened to `if(boolean_condition)`. And another one: `DataProduct` seems to be a parameter or variable. In that case it should be named `dataProduct` to avoid confusing it with a class name (see the Java code conventions for more information).

Comment: opps my bad, DataProduct is actually a string. Tenant_subscriptions is a list of IndexSub objects. IndexSub is an object that has various attributes such as IndexID

Answer (score 2):

[`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) functional interface has [`test()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#test(T)) method, not `apply()`:

```
if (order_function.get(DataProduct).test(s)){
    orderable_sub.add(s.getIndexId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to apply the same predicate to all elements in `tenant_subscriptions` you could use a stream:

```
Predicate<IndexSub> p = order_function.get(dataProduct);

if( p == null ) {
  //handle that case, e.g. set a default predicate or skip the following part
}

//this assumes tenant_subscriptions is a collection, if it is an array use Arrays.stream(...) or Stream.of(...)
Set<String> orderable_sub = tenant_subscriptions.stream() //create the stream
                               .filter(p) //apply the predicate
                               .map(IndexSub::getIndexId) //map all matching elements to their id
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet()); //collect the ids into a set
```